# ReferenceError: message is not defined but defined / Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined at

Tags: node.js

hey so i have a little problem and i'm a little bit broken :sad:
my bot saying ReferenceError: message is not defined but its defined so ?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./../config.json");
const moment = require('moment');
const chalk = require('chalk');
let prefix = config.prefix;


console.log(chalk.red(`[${moment().format(`YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`)}] - {${__filename}}:`), chalk.yellow(`Commande: a été utilisé par ${message.member.user.id} dans le channel #${message .channel.name}`));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    await message.delete();
        const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
        let banned = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
        if(!banned) return message.reply(`Mauvaise utilisation: \`${prefix}ban @user raison\``);
        if(banned.id === message.author.id) return message.reply("Argument incorrect: `Cet utilisateur est impossible a bannir`");
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Permission insufisante: `BAN_MEMBERS`");
        let banreason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
        if(!banreason) return message.reply(`Mauvaise utilisation: \`${prefix}ban @user raison\``);
        if(banned.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Argument incorrect: `Cet utilisateur est impossible a bannir`");

        banned.send(`Vous avez été banni de  **${message.channel.guild.name}** pour la raison suivante: **${banreason}**`);
        await delay(500);
        message.reply("User banni!");
        message.guild.member(banned).ban(banreason);
        return;
    }

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ban"
}
```

Idk why its not working...
So can u help me please ?

Thx.

Update:

So i rewrite a new code but i get this thing this time :

> Blockquote
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\maxim\OneDrive\projetRio\Quinella.js:282:22
>       at Map.every (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Collection.js:372:12)
>       at Client. (C:\Users\maxim\OneDrive\projetRio\Quinella.js:281:21)
>       at Client.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at Guild._updateMember (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1566:19)
>       at GuildMemberUpdateHandler.handle (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberUpdate.js:13:25)
>       at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
>       at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\maxim\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)

on this code :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
let prefix = config.prefix;
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();



fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Impossible de trouver une ou des commandes !");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} chargée!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});



fs.readdir("./commands/fun/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Impossible de trouver une ou des commandes !");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./commands/fun/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} chargée!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});



fs.readdir("./commands/general/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Impossible de trouver une ou des commandes !");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/general/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} chargée!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});



fs.readdir("./commands/moderation/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Impossible de trouver une ou des commandes !");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/moderation/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} chargée!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});



fs.readdir("./commands/nsfw/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Impossible de trouver une ou des commandes !");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/nsfw/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} chargée!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});





bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} id du bot:${bot.user.id} Crée le:${bot.user.createdAt}`);
  bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `https://www.eurotrans.me/ | ${prefix}help` }, status: 'dnd' });
});




bot.on("message", async message => {
  //a little bit of data parsing/general checks
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let content = message.content.split(" ");
  let command = content[0].toLowerCase();
  let args = content.slice(1);


  //checks if message contains a command and runs it
  let commandfile = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
  if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot,message,args);
});




const VERSION = '0.1.1';
const CHANNEL = 'log';


bot.on('ready', function() {
    console.log("[META][INFO] Connecter à L'API de Discord ");
});

//bot disconnected from Discord
bot.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log("[META][WARN] Deconnecter de L'API de Discord. Attempting to reconnected...");
});

//warning from Discord.js
bot.on('warn', function(msg) {
    console.log('[META][WARN] ' + msg);
});

//error from Discord.js
bot.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('[META][ERROR] ' + err.message);
    process.exit(1);
});

//message received
bot.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.author.id != bot.user.id) {
        if (message.channel.type == 'text')
            console.log('[' + message.guild.name + '][#' + message.channel.name + '][MSG] ' + message.author.username +
                '#' + message.author.discriminator + ': ' + formatConsoleMessage(message));
        else if (message.channel.type == 'dm')
            message.channel.sendMessage('Beep boop! Sorry, I can\'t respond to direct messages. ');
        else if (message.channel.type == 'group')
            message.channel.sendMessage('Beep boop! Sorry, I can\'t log group messages.');
    }
});

//message deleted
bot.on('messageDelete', function(message) {

    if(message.channel.type == 'text') {

        //log to console
        console.log('[' + message.guild.name + '][#' + message.channel.name + '][DELMSG] ' + message.author.username +
            '#' + message.author.discriminator + ': ' + formatConsoleMessage(message));

        //post in the guild's log channel
        var log = message.guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
        if (log != null)
            log.sendMessage('**[Message Deleted]** ' + message.author + ': ' + message.cleanContent);

    }

});

//message update
bot.on('messageUpdate', function(oldMessage, newMessage) {

    if (newMessage.channel.type == 'text' && newMessage.cleanContent != oldMessage.cleanContent) {

        //log to console
        console.log('[' + newMessage.guild.name + '][#' + newMessage.channel.name + '][UPDMSG] ' +
            newMessage.author.username + '#' + newMessage.author.discriminator + ':\n\tOLDMSG: ' +
            formatConsoleMessage(oldMessage) + '\n\tNEWMSG: ' + formatConsoleMessage(newMessage));

        //post in the guild's log channel
        var log = newMessage.guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
        if (log != null)
            log.sendMessage('**[Message Updated]** *' + newMessage.author + '*:\n*Old Message*: ' + oldMessage.cleanContent +
                '\n*New Message*: ' + newMessage.cleanContent);
    }

});

//user has been banned
bot.on('guildBanAdd', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][BAN] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null)
        log.sendMessage('**[Banned]** ' + user);

});

//user has been unbanned
bot.on('guildBanRemove', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UNBAN] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null)
        log.sendMessage('**[Unbanned]** ' + user);

});

//user has joined a guild
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][JOIN] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null) {
        log.sendMessage('**[Joined]** ' + user);
    }

});

//user has joined a guild
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][LEAVE] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null)
        log.sendMessage('**[Left]** ' + user);

});

//user in a guild has been updated
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', function(guild, oldMember, newMember) {

    //declare changes
    var Changes = {
        unknown: 0,
        addedRole: 1,
        removedRole: 2,
        username: 3,
        nickname: 4,
        avatar: 5
    };
    var change = Changes.unknown;

    //check if roles were removed
    var removedRole = '';
    oldMember.roles.every(function(value) {
        if(newMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.removedRole;
            removedRole = value.name;
        }
    });

    //check if roles were added
    var addedRole = '';
    newMember.roles.every(function(value) {
        if(oldMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.addedRole;
            addedRole = value.name;
        }
    });

    //check if username changed
    if(newMember.user.username != oldMember.user.username)
        change = Changes.username;

    //check if nickname changed
    if(newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname)
        change = Changes.nickname;

    //check if avatar changed
    if(newMember.user.avatarURL != oldMember.user.avatarURL)
        change = Changes.avatar;

    //log to console
    switch(change) {
        case Changes.unknown:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSR] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
        case Changes.addedRole:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][ADDROLE] ' + newMember.user.username +'#' +  newMember.user.discriminator +
                ': ' + addedRole);
            break;
        case Changes.removedRole:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][REMROLE] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator +
                ': ' + removedRole);
            break;
        case Changes.username:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSRNM] ' + oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator +
                ' is now ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
        case Changes.nickname:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSRNK] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator +
                (oldMember.nickname != null ? ' (' + oldMember.nickname + ')' : '') +
                (newMember.nickname != null ? ' is now ' + newMember.nickname : ' no longer has a nickname.'));
            break;
        case Changes.avatar:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDAVT] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
    }


    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null) {
        switch(change) {
            case Changes.unknown:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Update]** ' + newMember);
                break;
            case Changes.addedRole:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Role Added]** ' + newMember + ': ' + addedRole);
                break;
            case Changes.removedRole:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Role Removed]** ' + newMember + ': ' + removedRole);
                break;
            case Changes.username:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
                    oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
                    newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
                break;
            case Changes.nickname:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
                    (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
                        + newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
                    (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'));
                break;
            case Changes.avatar:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember);
                break;
        }
    }

});

//
// Startup Sequence
//
console.log('Logger Serveur' + VERSION);


console.log('[META][INFO] Started Logger Serveur' + VERSION);


function formatConsoleMessage(message) {
    return message.cleanContent.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'g'), '\n\t');
}



const active = new Map();


let ops = {
    active: active
};


bot.login("NjEzMDkwNzAwNTg1NzMwMDU0.XokdQw.Dfr4pd7glH0PsHr2BBb-");
```

Comment: in console.log, your using message var, its not defined

Comment: it still not working i'm pretty sure its just my code is broken i will jsut rewrite it :sad:

Comment: what's the exact error with stacktrace?, update your code in your question with your change

Comment: I rewrite a new code but i get a same thing with something else..
I update the code